# How to get live view of stdout and stderr of process which was created in c++ program?

Tags: c++, boost, process

I want to run process inside c++ program and be able to capture it's `stdout`, `stderr` during the process's lifetime (I figured out the `stdin` part). For that, I am using boost.process (1.81.0) on ubuntu 22.04 (but I want the solution to be cross-platform). Ultimately, I want to build my custom ssh (just for fun), so I need to be able to control shell's `stdout` and `stderr`. I launch the `test_program` inside `process_control` and I want be able to see live `stdout` and `stderr` output, but it is captured only after `test_program` terminates, which happens when I feed `end` as an input. Here are the code samples of mentioned programs:

**process_control.cpp**

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/process/pipe.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>

#include <thread>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    using namespace boost;

    std::string output{};
    std::string error{};

    asio::io_service ios;

    std::vector<char> vOut(128 << 10);
    auto outBuffer{asio::buffer(vOut)};
    process::async_pipe pipeOut(ios);

    std::function<void(const system::error_code &ec, std::size_t n)> onStdOut;
    onStdOut = [&](const system::error_code &ec, size_t n) {
        std::cout << "onSTDOUT CALLED.\n";
        output.reserve(output.size() + n);
        output.insert(output.end(), vOut.begin(), vOut.begin() + static_cast<long>(n));
        if (!ec) {
            asio::async_read(pipeOut, outBuffer, onStdOut);
        } else {
            std::cout << "STDOUT ERROR\n";
        }
        std::cout << output << "\n";
    };

    std::vector<char> vErr(128 << 10);
    auto errBuffer{asio::buffer(vErr)};
    process::async_pipe pipeErr(ios);
    std::function<void(const system::error_code &ec, std::size_t n)> onStdErr;
    onStdErr = [&](const system::error_code &ec, size_t n) {
        std::cout << "onSTDERR CALLED.\n";
        error.reserve(error.size() + n);
        error.insert(error.end(), vErr.begin(), vErr.begin() + static_cast<long>(n));
        if (!ec) {
            asio::async_read(pipeErr, errBuffer, onStdErr);
        } else {
            std::cout << "STDERR ERROR\n";
        }
        std::cout << error << "\n";
    };

    process::opstream in;
    process::child c(
            "test_program",
            process::std_out > pipeOut,
            process::std_err > pipeErr,
            process::std_in < in,
            ios
    );

    asio::async_read(pipeOut, outBuffer, onStdOut);
    asio::async_read(pipeErr, errBuffer, onStdErr);
    std::jthread t{[&ios] { ios.run(); }};

    std::cout<<"STARTING LOOP: \n";
    do {
        std::string input_command{};
        std::cout << "ENTER INPUT: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, input_command);
        if (c.running()) { //to prevent sigpipe if process dies during input
            in << input_command << std::endl;
        }
        std::this_thread::yield();
    } while (c.running());
    return 0;
}
```

**test_program.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>


using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {
    std::cout<<"Started program.\n";
    while(true){
        std::cout<<"Something\n";
        std::cerr<<"error stream\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(0.5s);
        if(std::rand()%3==0){
            std::cout<<"Waiting for input...\n";
            std::string input{};
            std::getline(std::cin, input);
            std::cout<<"Got input: \""<<input<<"\"\n";
            if(input=="end"){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the example output is:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPoI5.png)

How to capture stdout and stderr during the process's (in this case `test_program`) life?
What am I doing wrong here?
I also want to merge `stdout` and `stderr` into one output and also keep the chronological order, but I guess that could be done with passing the same buffer.

I also tried redirecting streams in shell like this:
`bash -c './test_program 2> stdout.txt 1> stderr.txt'`
and it worked fine, but did not work when I tried the same in c++ code

```
    process::child c(
            "bash -c './test_program 2> stdout.txt 1> stderr.txt'",
            process::std_in < in,
            ios
    );
```

and got output

```
STARTING LOOP: 
ENTER INPUT: 2>: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
2>: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
ls
end
```

or

```
    std::vector<std::string> args{{"-c"},{"'./test_program 2> stdout.txt 1> stderr.txt'"}};
    process::child c(
            "bash", process::args(args),
            process::std_in < in,
            ios
    );
```

and got output

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::process::process_error'
  what():  execve failed: No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

But redirecting to 2 separate files wouldn't really work for me, since I would like to maintain chronological order. So when tried
`bash -c './test_program 2> merged_output.txt 1> merged_output.txt'`
I was not surprised that the output wasn't looking good either.

**EDIT:**
I figured it out. For further reference, you can just simply create and use `FILE` instance, like this:

```
    std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&fclose)> p_stdout{fopen("output.txt", "w+"), fclose};
    process::child c(
            "test_program",
            process::std_out > p_stdout.get(),
            process::std_err > p_stdout.get(),
            process::std_in < in,
            ios
    );
```

and then open the same file in read mode

```
std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&fclose)> read_file{fopen("output.txt", "r"), fclose};
```

to read from it. You have to open it every time you want updated state, so I am not sure whether this approach is clean. But it works.

Comment: Why don't simply run `./test_program`? `test_program` is an executable binary, does not require a shell interpreter.

Comment: Because ultimately I want to build my own ssh, so I need to be able to controll shell's stdout and stderr, but the post is just simplified example of what I want to be able to achieve.

Comment: When you get redirection working, try `2>&1` in place of `2> merged_output.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you figured out. But I think the most important thing is that `async_read` doesn't complete unless the pipe is closed or the buffer is full. That makes no sense considering what you're doing.

Removing some duplication, I'd use `async_read_some`:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1124bea3addca77)** (referring to [*essentially unmodified* `test_program`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9dd53e263110b18e))

```
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/process/async.hpp>

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace bp   = boost::process;
using namespace std::placeholders;

struct PipeReader {
    using error_code = boost::system::error_code;
    using stringbuf  = asio::dynamic_string_buffer<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>;

    bp::async_pipe pipe;
    std::string    output;
    stringbuf      buf = asio::dynamic_buffer(output);
    std::ostream&  mirror;

    PipeReader(asio::io_service& ios, std::ostream& stream) : pipe(ios), mirror(stream) {}

    void read_loop(error_code ec = {}, size_t n = {}) {
        std::cerr << "[fd:" << pipe.native_source() << " " << n << ", " << ec.message() << "]";

        if (n) {
            buf.commit(n);

            if (mirror)
                mirror << std::string_view(output).substr(output.size() - n) << std::flush;
        }

        if (!ec)
            pipe.async_read_some(buf.prepare(512), std::bind(&PipeReader::read_loop, this, _1, _2));
    }
};

int main() {
    std::string error{};

    asio::io_context ios;

    PipeReader   pipeOut(ios, std::cout), pipeErr(ios, std::cerr);
    bp::opstream in;

    bp::child c(                    //
        "./build/test_program",     //
        bp::std_out > pipeOut.pipe, //
        bp::std_err > pipeErr.pipe, //
        bp::std_in < in,            //
        ios);

    pipeOut.read_loop();
    pipeErr.read_loop();

    std::jthread io_thread([&ios] { ios.run(); });

    std::cout << "STARTING LOOP: \n";
    for (std::string input_command{};
         std::cout << "ENTER INPUT: " && std::getline(std::cin, input_command) && c.running();
         std::this_thread::yield()) //
    {
        in << input_command << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "\n---\ntotal stdout:" << pipeOut.output.length() << ", stderr:" << pipeErr.output.length()
              << std::endl;
}
```

Local side-by-side demo to avoid the jumbling that happens on Coliru:

[image]

On the right is the `test_program` directly, on the left using Boost Process child process. The left side in text:

```
[fd:6 0, Success][fd:8 0, Success]STARTING LOOP:                               
ENTER INPUT: [fd:6 27, Success]Started program.                                                                                               
Something                                                                                                                                     
[fd:8 13, Success]error stream                                                                                                                
[fd:6 10, Success]Something                                                                                                                   
[fd:8 13, Success]error stream                                                                                                                                  
[fd:6 10, Success]Something                                                                                                                   
[fd:8 13, Success]error stream                                                                                                                
[fd:6 21, Success]Waiting for input...                                                                                                                          
foor                                                                                                                                                            
ENTER INPUT: [fd:6 28, Success]Got input: "foor"                                                                                                                
Something                                                                                                                                                       
[fd:8 13, Success]error stream                                                                                                                                  
[fd:6 10, Success]Something                                                                                                                                     
[fd:8 13, Success]error stream                                                                                                                                  
[fd:6 10, Success]Something                                                                                                                                     
[fd:8 13, Success]error stream                                                                                      
[fd:6 10, Success]Something                                                                                                                                     
[fd:8 13, Success]error stream                                                                                                                                  
[fd:6 10, Success]Something                                                                                                                                     
[fd:8 13, Success]error stream                                                                                                                                  
[fd:6 21, Success]Waiting for input...                                                                                                                          
bar                                                                                                                                                             
ENTER INPUT: [fd:6 27, Success]Got input: "bar"                                                                                                                 
Something                                                                                                                                                       
[fd:8 13, Success]error stream                                                                                                                                  
[fd:6 21, Success]Waiting for input...                                                            
end                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
ENTER INPUT: [fd:6 17, Success]Got input: "end"                                                                                                                                                                       
[fd:8 0, End of file][fd:6 0, End of file]                                                                                                                                                                            
---                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
total stdout:734, stderr:629
```

Comment: That is way better than my workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since `test_program` never outputs a `std::flush` or `std::endl` (which also does a flush), its output when going to a pipe will be buffered internally and will only be flushed when it calls exit.

If you want lines to be flushed sooner, use `std::endl` instead of `'\n'` (that's what it is for) or explicit `std::flush` at the points you want it to be flushed.

Comment: My answer demonstrates that this is not the issue here (likely streams auto-flush because input is involved)